# The spectral norm of projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given any $n \times n$ non-symmetric projection matrix $P$, i.e., $P^2 = P$ but $P^T \ne P$, is the spectral norm of $P$ bounded by a constant which is independent of the dimension $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $P$ is not bounded at all.

Take $\mathbb R^2$ and consider the projection onto $U=\{[1,0]^T\}$ along the orthogonal complement of $V_{\perp} := \{[\varepsilon,-1]^T\}_\perp$ given via $V = \{[1,\varepsilon ]^T\}$. Then $P = U(V^*U)^{-1}V^*$ has a spectral radius of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}}$, which can be arbitrarily large.

Please note that I have used $U$ and $V$ both to denote the subspace and to denote the matrices built up by the corresponding basis vectors...

Comment: Thanks! But $V$ should be $\{[\epsilon,1]^T\}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The formula is for the orthogonal complement. I have corrected this in the answer.